# Why does Ubuntu slow down after 5 minutes of working with it?

Tags: gnome, lubuntu, cinnamon

I am new to Ubuntu *(18.04)* and lately I am having problems with it, it turns out that when I start working on the computer everything is fine, terminal, shell, Firefox, Brave-Browser, folders will open in 1 second, but after 15 minutes working Ubuntu starts to crash, opening terminal and shell takes 15 seconds, opening my documents takes 30 seconds as well as displaying my applications.

I haven't downloaded anything weird, just python packages like Keras and TensorFlow.

I already delete temporary files, clean old files, and update ubuntu (`sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade, sudo apt-get clean, sudo apt-get autoremove`), GNOME Keyring: SHH Agent is the only startup program and I already installed preload.

What else can I do? Why does this not work?

I really don't know if it's a Gnome's problem. Should I switch to Cinnamon or Lubuntu? But I think my computer is not that bad (Lenovo ideapad 330s 15arr [AMD-Ryzen 5, Radeon VEGA, SSD 500GB, 8GB RAM) I also don't know if you should free up more RAM.

I'm really stuck here. Can someone help me?

*Yours sincerely*

*Best regards*

Comment: When it starts to slow open a terminal. Use the commands `top` and `free` to determine if you have a CPU bottleneck or a memory bottleneck. Don;t delete files at random - that almost never works in Linux.

Comment: You mention crash, if programs/applications crash there are usually .crash dumps in /var/crash/ that provide huge clues as to your problems (and can be fixed if reported). Your description implies thrashing to me (not crashing) but it's unclear. My desktop is eleven years old & I prefer Lubuntu (modern LXQt) over GNOME due to speed, however depending on how used switching DEsktops may not change things (does your DEs libs match apps you want to use? etc detail you can forget if you've enough ram for your intended use)

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and a screenshot of `top`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.